# How to tell JAXB to add noNameSpaceSchemaLocation attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

i have a certain class hierarchic which is transformed to XML using JAXB.
i want the created XML to have the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation and xmls:xsi attributes in the head element ( xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Something.xsd"  xmls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance").
i dont want JAXB do use the schema in any way - just store these attributes and the values.

is there a specific annotation for this? i could create just a constant XmlAttribute but it seems wrong...

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION` on the `Marshaller` like the following:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "address.xsd");
```

Comment: Thanks! will this add the xmls:xsi attribute as well with the XMLSchema-instance value?

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how to specify this as part of a `cxf-xjc-plugin` code generation phase in maven (where the `Marhsaller` is not directly accessed) ?